# Consolidate flag columns into single column in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe like this

```
testtbl <- data.frame(ID = c('1','2','3','4'),
                      A = c(1,0,1,1),
                      B = c(1,1,1,1),
                      C = c(0,0,0,1),
                      D = c(0,1,1,1))

> testtbl
  ID A B C D
1  1 1 1 0 0
2  2 0 1 0 1
3  3 1 1 0 1
4  4 1 1 1 1
```

Where columns `A`-`D` are flags that can either be 1 or 0. I would like to consolidate these columns into 1 column, where the new dataframe would look something like:

```
> testtbl
  ID flag
1  1 A,B
2  2 B,D
3  3 A,B,D
4  4 A,B,C,D
```

At little confused on how I would approach this and would appreciate any hints or help.

Comment: `df = reshape2::melt(testtbl, id.vars = "ID"); aggregate(as.character(variable)~ID, df[df$value == 1,], '[', simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: This works, thanks @d.b can you repost as an answer and maybe step through it for clarification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution from `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
testtbl2 <- testtbl %>%
  gather(Col, Val, -ID) %>%
  filter(Val == 1) %>%
  select(-Val) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(flag = toString(Col))
testtbl2
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#       ID       flag
#   <fctr>      <chr>
# 1      1       A, B
# 2      2       B, D
# 3      3    A, B, D
# 4      4 A, B, C, D
```

Comment: I think this should still work without the `arrange(ID, Col)` line

Comment: The data.table analogue: `library(data.table); melt(setDT(testtbl))[, .(flag = toString(variable[as.logical(value)])), by=ID]`. Btw, with filter(Val == 1), you will drop IDs with no flags, which isn't desirable, eh.

Comment: @markdly You are right. I will update my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @ycw For some reason I'm getting an error on the `select` line;


Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Comment: You probably loaded other packages also with a `select` function. Try `dplyr::select` to be specific.

Comment: I run it again, specifying the package, but it returns a named vector and not a dataframe.

Comment: It should work, at least for your example dataset. Are you working on your example dataset or your real-world dataset? Re-start an R session could be helpful.

Comment: @KyleWeise, ycw's code is working fine for me. Perhaps try rerunning in a new R session

Comment: Thank you @ycw and markdly. Not sure what was up but restarting R session did the trick. Going to accept this answer asI am a bit biased towards the tidyverse, but other answers have also worked.

Comment: @Frank In my actual data, the `ID` column is actually a combination of 3 separate columns. I can use the function `unite()` to do this the tidyverse way, I am curious to know if you know of a way I can achieve the same using `data.table`? Recently saw that `data.table`'s `fread()` was significantly faster than `readr`'s `read_*()`, so I was considering benchmarking this operation for both packages. (if you're curious, here's the link https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/5-3-importing-data.html )

Comment: @KyleWeise Thanks for the link. Yeah, I use fread/fwrite mostly so that I don't have to fiddle with input of strings and output of dates. I am not sure what `unite` does, but it sounds the same as `paste` from base, so I guess data.table wouldn't add something for such functionality. The have implemented one string function in data.table already (`tstrsplit`), but only because there are some efficiency issues to consider, not just syntactical sugar, I think. I could be wrong though; if you think it'd be useful, you could file a FR with the package.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it without any libraries with an apply:

```
testtbl <- data.frame(ID = c('1','2','3','4'),
                  A = c(1,0,1,1),
                  B = c(1,1,1,1),
                  C = c(0,0,0,1),
                  D = c(0,1,1,1))
test<-data.frame(ID=testtbl$ID, flag=(apply(testtbl[,-1], 1, function(x) paste0(names(x)[which(x==1)], collapse=','))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(testtbl, testtbl$ID), function(x)
    data.frame(ID = x[1],
               flag = paste(sort(names(x)[-1][x[-1] > 0]),
                            collapse = ","))))
#  ID    flag
#1  1     A,B
#2  2     B,D
#3  3   A,B,D
#4  4 A,B,C,D
```